# After setting up an a Static IP address on netplan, I cant access the internet

Tags: server, xubuntu, netplan

I am currently using ubuntu LTS and I am trying to set a static IP address because I plan on using K3sup.

After doing some research, I have changed

```
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

to these settings

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.1.83/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
             addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
    version: 2
```

I have applied the settings and it has seemed to accept the new ip address. The problem is when I ping google, nothing goes through.

What is the issue here?

Comment: your gateway is not on the same sub-net as your static IP. try 192.168.0.83/24 or 192.168.1.83/23, depending on your requirements.

Comment: When turning on DCHP, it worked. The goal is for me to have it off, I am confused why this happened

Comment: What address and sub-net mask does it get with DHCP? On Static can you ping google via IP address? i.e. is it just DNS that isn't working or internet access in general. Regardless, your gateway has to be on the same sub-net as your IP address.